# Support for an intermediate table with composite primary keys in Django 3.2

Tags: python, django-models

I have a set of Django 3.2 models defined below. When I use the admin UI to add a new challenge then it fails with *"column challenge_countries.id does not exist"*. How can I let Django know that the `ChallengeCountry` model does not contain an `id` column but instead has a composite primary key made of the columns `challenge_id` and `country_id`?

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    country_name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    country_iso = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "countries"

class ChallengeCountry(models.Model):
    challenge = models.ForeignKey(
        "Challenge",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="challenge",
        db_column="challenge_id"
    )
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country,
        on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        related_name="country",
        db_column="country_id"
    )

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "challenge_countries"
        unique_together = ["challenge", "country"]

class Challenge(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False,
    )
    name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(
        Country,
        related_name="challenges",
        verbose_name="country",
        blank=True,
        through=ChallengeCountry,
        through_fields=("challenge", "country")
    )

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "challenges"
```

**NOTE**: I do not have the freedom to add an `id` column to the `challenge_countries` table

I have also tried removing `unique_together` from `ChallengeCountry` and instead added `primary_key=True` to both the `challenge` and `country` fields in that model but that resulted in this error during migration:

```
pipenv run python manage.py migrate
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'challenges.admin.ChallengesAdmin'>: (admin.E013) The value of 'fieldsets[1][1]["fields"]' cannot include the ManyToManyField 'countries', because that field manually specifies a relationship model.
challenges.ChallengeCountry: (models.E026) The model cannot have more than one field with 'primary_key=True'.
```

The `ChallengesAdmin` that this error refers to has the following code snippet:

```
class ChallengesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ChallengeForm
    ...
    filter_horizontal = [
        "countries",
    ]
    fieldsets = [
        (
            None,
            {
                "fields": [
                    "id",
                    "name",
                    ...
                ]
            },
        ),
        (
            "Countries",
            {
                "fields": ["countries"],
                "description": """
                    If no countries are selected,
                    the challenge will be visible to all users
                """,
            },
        ),
    ]
    ...
```

Comment: Django has no composite primary keys.

Comment: If you only plan to *read* from the database, it however is not that much of a problem: then you can just use any field as primary key.

Comment: I will need to add records to the DB as well

Comment: What is strange is that with the `primary_key=True` solution I am able to add/edit records - its just the migration step that errors.

Comment: updates will likely not work completely: if you have two primary keys pk1 and pk2, it will eventually use `UPDATE FROM TABLE ... WHERE pk1 = some_val`, so that means it will override multiple records if that key occurs multiple times.